# Can I use a UDOO as an Arduino?

Tags: atmel-studio

I have a UDOO, and I wonder whether or not it is possible to use the Arduino that it has without starting the UDOO's operating system, i.e., I would like use Atmel Studio to load a program within the Arduino at UDOO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you have to erase the flash (and reset the ATMEL SAM3X8E processor) manually before the programming. You can use the J16 and J22 jumpers to do this.